# Mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes. Help to find a reason

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-support-library

All my dependencies start from a verson 27, but the build task is still finishing with an Exception:

> Error: All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.1.1, 25.4.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 and com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0 [GradleCompatible]

I know that I can add

```
  lintOptions {
      abortOnError false
  }
```

and it will fix my issue, but I want to establish the reason.

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.company.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.10.8"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            buildConfigField("String", "ENV_URL_PREFIX", "\"https://\"")
            buildConfigField("String", "ENVIRONMENT", "\"release\"")
        }

        staging {
            initWith debug

            buildConfigField("String", "ENV_URL_PREFIX", "\"https://staging.\"")
            buildConfigField("String", "ENVIRONMENT", "\"staging\"")
        }

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            buildConfigField("String", "ENV_URL_PREFIX", "\"https://dev.\"")
            buildConfigField("String", "ENVIRONMENT", "\"dev\"")
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "app"
    productFlavors {
        _Live {
            dimension "app"
            buildConfigField("String", "TYPE", "\"live\"")
        }
        _Test {
            dimension "app"
            buildConfigField("String", "TYPE", "\"test\"")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'lib/x86_64/darwin/libscrypt.dylib'
        exclude 'lib/x86_64/freebsd/libscrypt.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86_64/linux/libscrypt.so'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.1.0'
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.4'
    implementation 'com.crowdfire.cfalertdialog:cfalertdialog:1.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:zxing-parent:3.3.3'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:22.0'

    implementation project(':mobile_api') // a module compiled with java plugin

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
}
```

My idea that some of the dependencies transit a com.android.support libraries with version 25.4.0.
I would be grateful for any suggestions.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check in mobile_api project build gradle file and change their also to 27.1.1. Also use CMD + SHIFT + F and search with 25.4.0 if you find in any file with in the project in any module which the project is dependent on, change it to 27.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using this library 'com.crowdfire.cfalertdialog:cfalertdialog:1.1.0', 
and it in turn uses [dependency](https://github.com/Codigami/CFAlertDialog/blob/master/cfalertdialog/build.gradle) 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0'
Perhaps this is the cause of the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the very end of your root level build.gradle:

```
configurations.all { 
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details -> 
        def requested = details.requested 
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support')  { details.useVersion '27.x.x' } 
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix it I added a dependency

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
```

in my build.gradle which overrides 25.4.0. Therefore, you do not need to look for a dependency that includes a breaking library.